# Documentation editor confuses words with characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

How to replicate:

1. Edit any empty Documentation introduction
2. Type `n` letters

In the bottom right corner at the *Topic Outline* you see `{n} words added` instead of `{n} characters added` or the correct number of words.

Comment: I noticed this the other day. Due to holidays, it's not been fixed quite yet. But it will be once a dev has a few minutes to fix it.

Comment: @JonEricson Maybe 6-8 weeks :)

Comment: +Jon Ericson Just enjoy your holidays, it's such a minor bug. Next time I will tell a developer in chat instead of opening a meta topic ;)

Comment: It's a bit easier for me to make sure this sort of bug is fixed on meta. Chat's great, but unless there's an immediate fix, we're likely to lose track there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.